# Why didn't Torricelli use other liquids?

Tags: physics, biographical-details

Why did [Torricelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelista_Torricelli) use a denser liquid like mercury? Why didn't he think of using lighter liquids like water?

Comment: Because you need more of a lighter fluid to balance the same weight of air, that is what makes it "lighter". Even water filled "barometers" (of course, they were not interpreted as such) used before Torricelli were too long and impractical, see [Torricelli and the Ocean of Air](https://www.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/physiol.00053.2012).

Comment: He argued that if a vacuum was responsible for attracting the mercury, the heights of the columns would be different            Can you explain this sentence?

Comment: Is at those time it was thought that vacuum attracts things??

Comment: Yes, it was Aristotle's contention that "nature abhors vacuum" and tries to fill it. Galileo still believed it.

Comment: Thank you conifold

Comment: Can you provide an example of which thing he considered as vacuum is being filled by something?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you understand the mechanism of a barometer, so I apologize if this is redundant.
  The denser the fluid, the smaller the height of fluid required to balance 1 atmophere pressure.  Simplify your engineering at all times.
In addition, selecting a fluid with very low vapor pressure means you have the least amount of error caused by the not-quite-vacuum region above the fluid in the closed tower. In fact, precision barometers have a thin layer of specialized oil placed on top of the Hg because this oil's vapor pressure is even lower than that of Hg.  (and it's trivial to calculate the mass offset of this layer).

Comment: Please can you explain the denser the fluid the smaller the height of fluid required to balance 1atmospheric pressure

Comment: I can't understand

Comment: In that time were they knowing that the denser the fluid, the smaller the height of the fluid required to balance 1 atmospheric pressure

Comment: @user230720  I don't think I can give an explanation to your satisfaction.  Perhaps you should start by finding some tutorials which explain what "pressure" and "density" mean.